# Memory leak on Liferay 6.2 migration

Tags: java, memory-leaks, liferay, liferay-6

I've migrated a Liferay 6.2-CE-GA2 server from Liferay 6.1.1-ce-ga2.

I made a few changes in custom hooks and themes to addapt to the new version.

On locale I have never had a problem with memory nor with the 6.1 version, but once in production, server runs out of memory in a few hours.

I tried to adjust heap parameters and increasing server memory (from 2GB to 3GB) but it seems that the heap keeps growking slowly but non-stopping, until I get an `OutOfMemory: Java heap space` or, if I grant bigger limits to the heap, system runs out of memory.

I've been some days studying catalina.out, trying to minimize warnings and errors and this is the only interesting things I've seen  during a shutdown-reboot process (I replaced all domain names on logs):

```
[on shutdown]
WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.

[...]

28-xul-2014 16:53:51 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.python.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
28-xul-2014 16:53:51 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-26] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
28-xul-2014 16:53:51 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-27] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

[...]

16:55:40,517 ERROR [liferay/hot_deploy-1][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] Batch entry 0 insert into CalendarBooking (uuid_, groupId, companyId, userId, userName, createDate, modifiedDate, resourceBlockId, calendarId, calendarResourceId, parentCalendarBookingId, title, description, location, startTime, endTime, allDay, recurrence, firstReminder, firstReminderType, secondReminder, secondReminderType, status, statusByUserId, statusByUserName, statusDate, calendarBookingId) values ('985aac08-6457-484c-becb-2c4964805158', '10545', '10154', '10196', 'Carlos Ces', '2012-06-06 06:26:41.431000 +01:00:00', '2012-06-06 06:26:41.431000 +01:00:00', '0', '550617', '550571', '565201', 'Master Class de improvisación e tango contemporáneo con Jorge Retamoza', '<p>_    <a href="http://www.rrrrrr.es/cultura/-/blogs/master-class-de-improvisacion-e-tango-contemporaneo-con-jorge-retamoza">Master Class con Jorge Retamoza. </a></p>_<p>_    <a href="http://www.rrrrrr.es/cultura/-/blogs/master-class-de-improvisacion-e-tango-contemporaneo-con-jorge-retamoza">Organiza: Escola de Música de rrrrrr. Colabora: Concello de rrrrrr.</a></p>', 'Auditorio de rrrrrr', '1339246800000', '1339257600000', '0', '', '900000', 'email', '300000', 'email', '0', '10196', 'Carlos Ces', '2012-06-06 06:26:41.431000 +01:00:00', '565201') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause. [Sanitized]
16:55:40,518 ERROR [liferay/hot_deploy-1][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_f4c61797"
16:55:40,536 ERROR [liferay/hot_deploy-1][SerialDestination:68] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/hot_deploy, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=null, values={command=deploy, companyId=0, servletContextName=calendar-portlet}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:32)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.SerialDestination$1.run(SerialDestination.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    [...]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    [...]
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into CalendarBooking (uuid_, groupId, companyId, userId, userName, createDate, modifiedDate, resourceBlockId, calendarId, calendarResourceId, parentCalendarBookingId, title, description, location, startTime, endTime, allDay, recurrence, firstReminder, firstReminderType, secondReminder, secondReminderType, status, statusByUserId, statusByUserName, statusDate, calendarBookingId) values ('985aac08-6457-484c-becb-2c4964805158', '10545', '10154', '10196', 'Carlos Ces', '2012-06-06 06:26:41.431000 +01:00:00', '2012-06-06 06:26:41.431000 +01:00:00', '0', '550617', '550571', '565201', 'Master Class de improvisación e tango contemporáneo con Jorge Retamoza', '<p>_  <a href="http://www.rrrrrr.es/cultura/-/blogs/master-class-de-improvisacion-e-tango-contemporaneo-con-jorge-retamoza">Master Class con Jorge Retamoza. </a></p>_<p>_    <a href="http://www.rrrrrr.es/cultura/-/blogs/master-class-de-improvisacion-e-tango-contemporaneo-con-jorge-retamoza">Organiza: Escola de Música de rrrrrr. Colabora: Concello de rrrrrr.</a></p>', 'Auditorio de rrrrrr', '1339246800000', '1339257600000', '0', '', '900000', 'email', '300000', 'email', '0', '10196', 'Carlos Ces', '2012-06-06 06:26:41.431000 +01:00:00', '565201') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause. [Sanitized]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2621)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1837)
    [...]
    ... 68 more
```

Then server runs properly for 5 hours with some spared warnings each few minutes:

```
23:39:09,275 WARN  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-20][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:623] Reject process action for http://www.rrrrrr.com/rrrrrr25n/notadeprensa on 56_INSTANCE_rk7ADlb9Ui2w
23:43:51,234 WARN  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-19][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:623] Reject process action for http://www.rrrrrr.org/feiron/normas on 56_INSTANCE_jh6ewEPuvvjb
23:46:59,568 WARN  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-5][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:623] Reject process action for http://www.rrrrrr.es/recursos-servizossociais on 56_INSTANCE_4eX2GzETiAQb
23:55:51,177 WARN  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-5][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:623] Reject process action for http://www.rrrrrr.es/cans on 56_INSTANCE_4eX2GzETiAQb
00:00:13,713 WARN  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-24][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:623] Reject process action for http://www.rrrrrr.es/rexistro on 56_INSTANCE_4eX2GzETiAQb
00:00:25,822 WARN  [ajp-apr-8009-exec-24][SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:623] Reject process action for http://www.rrrrrr.es/plenos on 110_INSTANCE_acNEFnslrX8c
```

And then memory problems begin. I post the first errors on log:

```
Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
01:00:01,223 ERROR [MemoryQuartzSchedulerEngineInstance_Worker-3][SimpleThreadPool:120] Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "fileinstall-/home/rrrrrr/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/data/osgi/modules" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-AsyncTimeout" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-21"   at java.util.LinkedHashMap.createEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:441)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.addEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:423)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:402)
Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-24"  at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.loadLookup(OpenListResourceBundle.java:134)
Exception in thread "MemoryQuartzSchedulerEngineInstance_QuartzSchedulerThread" Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]"    at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.loadLookupTablesIfNecessary(OpenListResourceBundle.java:113)
Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-35" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-36" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-29" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-37"     at sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle.handleGetKeys(OpenListResourceBundle.java:91)
    at sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObjectImpl(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:353)
Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-33" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-34" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-30"    at sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObject(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:284)
Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-28" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-31" Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-AsyncTimeout" Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-5" Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-2" Exception in thread "liferay/scheduler_dispatch-3" Exception in thread "ajp-apr-8009-exec-41"  at sun.util.TimeZoneNameUtility.retrieveDisplayNames(TimeZoneNameUtility.java:111)
    at sun.util.TimeZoneNameUtility.retrieveDisplayNames(TimeZoneNameUtility.java:99)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDisplayNames(TimeZone.java:418)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDisplayName(TimeZone.java:369)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:1110)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:899)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:869)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.appendCookieValue(ServerCookie.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:381)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addCookie(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.HttpOnlyCookieServletResponse.addCookie(HttpOnlyCookieServletResponse.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addCookie(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addCookie(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addCookie(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.addCookie(MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.java:128)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addCookie(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.addCookie(MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.java:128)
01:02:56,362 ERROR [PersistedQuartzSchedulerEngineInstance_QuartzSchedulerThread][ErrorLogger:120] An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'ds': java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space [See nested exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:771)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3808)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2751)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:264)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.addCookie(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.addCookie(MetaInfoCacheServletResponse.java:128)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CookieKeys.addCookie(CookieKeys.java:99)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CookieKeys.addCookie(CookieKeys.java:63)
    at com.liferay.portal.language.LanguageImpl.updateCookie(LanguageImpl.java:751)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
01:03:00,917 ERROR [QuartzScheduler_PersistedQuartzSchedulerEngineInstance-NON_CLUSTERED_MisfireHandler][PortalJobStore:120] MisfireHandler: Error handling misfires: Unexpected runtime exception: Index: 0, Size: 0
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Unexpected runtime exception: Index: 0, Size: 0 [See nested exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3200)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3947)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3968)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1689)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.countMisfiredTriggersInState(StdJDBCDelegate.java:416)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3176)
    ... 2 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "fileinstall-/home/rrrrrr/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/data/osgi/portal" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have some custom themes and hooks that I now post. I wonder there has to be a memory leak anywhere on them, but i cannot find it.

First, I have a custom `Application Display Template`for Blogs:

```
<div class="cr-blog container-fluid">
 #foreach ($entry in $entries)
 <div class="entry-content">
  #set ($viewUrl = $currentURL.replaceFirst("\?.*$","") + "/-/blogs/" + $entry.getUrlTitle())
  #set($img_ini=$entry.content.indexOf("<img"))

  #if ($img_ini >= 0)
   #set($img_end=$entry.content.indexOf(">",$img_ini) + 1)
   #set($first_img_tag= $entry.content.substring($img_ini, $img_end))

   #set($first_img_url=$first_img_tag.replaceFirst("<img.*src=\"",""))
   #set($first_img_url=$first_img_url.replaceFirst("\".*","")) 
  #end

  <div class="entry-extract">

   #if ($img_ini >= 0)
   <div class="extract-thumbnail">
     <a href="$viewUrl">
      <img src="$escapeTool.html($first_img_url)" />
     </a>
   </div>
   #end

   <div class="extract-title">
    <a href="$viewUrl"><span>$entry.title</span></a>
   </div>


   <div class="extract-content">
    <a href="$viewUrl">
     <span class="extract-date">$dateFormats.getSimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy HH:mm", $locale).format($entry.displayDate)</span>
      #set($plain_content = $entry.content.replaceAll("</?[^>]+/?>", ""))
      #set($res_length = 240)
      #if ($res_length > $plain_content.length())
       #set($res_length = $plain_content.length())
      #end
      <p>
       $plain_content.substring(0,$res_length) ...
      </p>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 #end
</div>
```

Custom hook Blogshome overrides some jsps from blogs_aggregator.

view_entries.jspf

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= results.isEmpty() %>">
        <liferay-ui:message key="there-are-no-blogs" />

        <br /><br />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>

        <%

        if (displayStyle.startsWith("extract-side-events")) {

            List<BlogsEntry> eventsColumn = new ArrayList<BlogsEntry>();
            List<BlogsEntry> mainColumn = new ArrayList<BlogsEntry>();

            for (int i=0; i< results.size(); i++) {
                BlogsEntry entry = (BlogsEntry) results.get(i);

                if (entry.getDisplayDate().after(new Date())) {
                    searchContainer.setTotal(searchContainer.getTotal() - 1);
                    continue;
                }



                boolean isEvent = ((Boolean) entry.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("evento"));

                if (isEvent) eventsColumn.add(entry);
                mainColumn.add(entry); /* change: add ALL to mainColumn; events are duplicated on side */
            }

                        /* reorder eventsColumn */

                        TreeMap<Date, BlogsEntry> next= new TreeMap<Date, BlogsEntry>();
            List<BlogsEntry> toRemove = new ArrayList<BlogsEntry>();

                for (BlogsEntry entry: eventsColumn) {
                                Date ini = (Date) entry.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("evento-inicio");
                                Date end = (Date) entry.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("evento-remate");
                                Date now = new Date();

                                if (ini.before(now) && (end.after(now))) {
                    next.put(end, entry);
                    /* mainColumn.remove(entry); */
                } else if (end.before(now)) {
                    toRemove.add(entry);
                } else {
                    next.put(ini, entry);
                    /* mainColumn.remove(entry); */
                }
                        }
            eventsColumn.removeAll(toRemove);

            /* third rearrangement: current & next are visible; past are pushed to mainColumn */
            /* current ordered by end; next ordered by ini */

                        ArrayList<BlogsEntry> lNext = new ArrayList<BlogsEntry>(next.values());

                        %> <div class="home-events">
                <div class="events-showdown" id="events-showdown">


            <%
                if (!lNext.isEmpty()) { 

                                for (BlogsEntry entry: lNext) {
                                        %>  
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                                <%@ include file="/html/portlet/blogs_aggregator/view_entry_extract.jspf" %>
                            </div>
                                        <%                                    
                                }
                }
            %>

                </div>
                <script>
                    YUI().use('aui-carousel', function(Y) { new Y.Carousel( {contentBox: '#events-showdown',
                        height: 320, width: 600, intervalTime: 5 }).render(); });
                </script>
<%--
                <div class="home-events-nav">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-large"
                    onclick="document.getElementById('events-showdown').style.right =50">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
--%>
            </div> <%


                        %> <div class="home-blogs container-fluid" > <%                    
                        for (BlogsEntry entry: mainColumn) {
                                    %>  
                                        <%@ include file="/html/portlet/blogs_aggregator/view_entry_extract.jspf" %>
                                    <%
                        }
                        %> </div> <%


                /* original blogs styles */        
                } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                BlogsEntry entry = (BlogsEntry)results.get(i);

                if (entry.getDisplayDate().after(new Date())) {
                    searchContainer.setTotal(searchContainer.getTotal() - 1);
                    continue;
                }
            %>  
                <%@ include file="/html/portlet/blogs_aggregator/view_entry_content.jspf" %>
            <%
            }
        }
        %>

    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<c:if test="<%= enableRssSubscription %>">

    <%
    StringBundler rssURLParams = new StringBundler();

    if (selectionMethod.equals("users")) {
        if (organizationId > 0) {
            rssURLParams.append("&organizationId=");
            rssURLParams.append(organizationId);
        }
        else {
            rssURLParams.append("&companyId=");
            rssURLParams.append(company.getCompanyId());
        }
    }
    else {
        rssURLParams.append("&groupId=");
        rssURLParams.append(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
    }
    %>

    <span class="button">
        <liferay-ui:icon
            image="rss"
            label="<%= true %>"
            method="get"
            target="_blank"
            url='<%= themeDisplay.getPathMain() + "/blogs_aggregator/rss?p_l_id=" + plid + rssURLParams %>'
        />
    </span>
</c:if>

<c:if test="<%= !results.isEmpty() %>">
    <div class="search-container">
        <liferay-ui:search-paginator searchContainer="<%= searchContainer %>" />
    </div>
</c:if>
```

view_entry_extract.jspf

```
<c:if test="<%= BlogsEntryPermission.contains(permissionChecker, entry, ActionKeys.VIEW) %>">
    <div class="entry-content">

        <%
        PortletURL showBlogEntryURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL();

        showBlogEntryURL.setParameter("struts_action", "/blogs_aggregator/view_entry");
        showBlogEntryURL.setParameter("entryId", String.valueOf(entry.getEntryId()));

        StringBundler sb = new StringBundler(8);

        StringBundler ab = new StringBundler(8);
        ab.append(themeDisplay.getURLPortal());
        ab.append(GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(entry.getGroupId()).getFriendlyURL());
        ab.append("/-/blogs/");
        ab.append(entry.getUrlTitle());

        String viewEntryURL = ab.toString();

        sb.append("&showAllEntries=1");

        String viewAllEntriesURL = sb.toString();

        User user2 = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserById(entry.getUserId());
        %>

        <div class="entry-header">

            <c:if test='<%= (Boolean) entry.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("evento")%>'>
                <div class="event-schedule">

        <%

                        Calendar iniDate = com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar(timeZone);
                        Calendar endDate = com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar(timeZone);
                        iniDate.setTime(((Date) entry.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("evento-inicio")));
                        endDate.setTime(((Date) entry.getExpandoBridge().getAttribute("evento-remate")));
                                                                            boolean sameDay = false;

                        if ((iniDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
                         && (iniDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) == endDate.get(Calendar.YEAR))) 
                sameDay = true;

            String diaDaSemana = (new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", locale)).format(iniDate.getTime());
            String numeroDeDia = (new SimpleDateFormat("d", locale)).format(iniDate.getTime());
            String mes = (new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", locale)).format(iniDate.getTime());
//          String hora = (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", locale)).format(iniDate.getTime()) + "h"; 
            String hora = (iniDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +  new SimpleDateFormat(":mm", locale).format(iniDate.getTime()) + "h");

            String numeroDeDiaFin = StringPool.BLANK;
            String mesFin = StringPool.BLANK;
            if (!sameDay) {
                numeroDeDiaFin = (new SimpleDateFormat("d", locale)).format(endDate.getTime());
                mesFin = (new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", locale)).format(endDate.getTime());
            }

        %>

        <%
            if (sameDay) {
        %>
            <div class='event-date'>
                <%= numeroDeDia %>
            </div>
            <div class='event-data'>
                <div class="event-month"><%= mes  %></div>
                <div class="event-day"><%= diaDaSemana  %></div>
                <div class="event-time"><%= hora  %></div>
            </div>

        <%
            } else {
        %>
            <div class='event-date'>
                <%= numeroDeDia %>
            </div>
            <div class='event-data'>
                <div class="event-month"><%= mes  %></div>
                <div class="event-day"><%= diaDaSemana  %></div>
                <div class="event-time"><liferay-ui:message key="rrrrrr.events.until" /> <%= numeroDeDiaFin %> 
                            <liferay-ui:message key="rrrrrr.events.of" /> <%= mesFin  %></div>
            </div>

        <%

            }
        %>          

                </div>
            </c:if>


        </div>

        <div class="entry-extract">

            <%

            String resumeText = StringPool.BLANK;
            String resumeImage = StringPool.BLANK;
            int extLength = 240;

            if (entry.isSmallImage()) {
                if (Validator.isNotNull(entry.getSmallImageURL()))
                    resumeImage = entry.getSmallImageURL();
                else
                    resumeImage = themeDisplay.getPathImage() + "/journal/article?img_id=" + entry.getSmallImageId() + "&t=" + WebServerServletTokenUtil.getToken(entry.getSmallImageId()) ;
                resumeImage.trim();
            }

            /* if no small image, extract first */
            if ((resumeImage == null) || (resumeImage.isEmpty())) {

                java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("src=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]");
                java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(entry.getContent());
                if (m.find())
                    resumeImage = m.group().substring(5, m.group().length() -1);
            }

            resumeText = HtmlUtil.stripHtml(entry.getDescription());
            resumeText.trim();

            /* if no resume description, extract text */
            if ((resumeText == null) || (resumeText.isEmpty())) {
                resumeText = HtmlUtil.escape(StringUtil.shorten(HtmlUtil.extractText(entry.getContent()), extLength));
            }

            %>

            <div class="extract-thumbnail">
                <a href="<%= viewEntryURL %>"  style="background-image: url('<%= HtmlUtil.escape(resumeImage) %>')">
                    <img class="asset-small-image" src="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(resumeImage) %>"/> 
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="extract-title">
                <a href="<%= viewEntryURL %>"><%= HtmlUtil.escape(entry.getTitle()) %></a>
            </div>

            <div class="extract-content">
                <a href="<%= viewEntryURL %>">
                    <span class="extract-scope"><%= GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(entry.getGroupId()).getDescriptiveName() %></span> 
                    <span class="extract-date"><%= dateFormatDateTime.format(entry.getDisplayDate()) %></span> 
                    <span><%= " " + resumeText %></span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I am unable to guess any memory leak there, but there has to be! I've spent few weeks trying to find a bug (deactivating hooks to see if errors persisted) but couldn't come to a clue.

Does anybody see something potentially dangerous in my code? Wich other way can I trace Java memory usage to fetch for leaks?

Answer (score 0):

That is really a messy code... 
First do not use scriplets use servlets.

Do not throw that amount of code at as identify your problem and then narrow down your question so we can answer it.

 You can make use of MAT in eclipse take stack dump and analyze what objects take up most amount of memory and therefore what is a cause of the memory leak.

 Why are you mixing JSTL with scriplets? JSTL is design to work with servlets.

You mix up business logic with presentation layer it is why scriplets are strongly not recommended. Your code is not readable messy come back when you change it to scriplets and then I would be able to give you some answers.

Comment: I of course do prefer use of Servlets before scriptlets, but Liferay puts a lot of scriptlets into jsp pages - I don't know why. These two jsp pages are slightly modifications of the originals of the Liferay platform; I needed a few changes so I used Liferay's hooks technology to make those minimal changes in jsp files.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you describe fit with the memory leak. In case you suspect one, give [Plumbr](https://plumbr.eu) a try to find the cause and solve it. In case you just need more information about the [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) you are facing, see the informational post about the error, possible causes and solution means.